# Parsing a xml in php

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML feed that has content like this

```
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="propiedades.xsd" generated="2015-04-28T15:16:46">
<propiedades>
<Descripcion>Excelente casa de dos pisos en condominio en la urbanización Santa Maria De Villa Club, en Carabayllo, con un AT:92m2 y un AC:113m2, cuenta con 3 iluminadas habitaciones, 3 baños, cochera, de estreno, con áreas verdes, piscina, cancha de fútbol, salones para actividades. ¡Para más información contactarse con nuestros agente!ID:   35751</Descripcion>
<Foto1>http://www.alfredograf.com/fotoprop/mini-35751%20-%201.jpg</Foto1>
<Foto2>http://www.alfredograf.com/fotoprop/mini-35751%20-%202.jpg</Foto2>
<Foto3>http://www.alfredograf.com/fotoprop/mini-35751%20-%203.jpg</Foto3>
<Foto4>http://www.alfredograf.com/fotoprop/mini-35751%20-%204.jpg</Foto4>
<Foto5>http://www.alfredograf.com/fotoprop/mini-35751%20-%205.jpg</Foto5>
<Foto6>http://www.alfredograf.com/fotoprop/mini-35751%20-%206.jpg</Foto6>
<Foto7>http://www.alfredograf.com/fotoprop/mini-35751%20-%207.jpg</Foto7>
<Foto8>http://www.alfredograf.com/fotoprop/mini-35751%20-%208.jpg</Foto8>
</propiedades>
</dataroot>
```

I wanted to know how I can extract the Images because every images have different XML name . like Fotos1,2,3 etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an xpath query to target the node names that starts with `Foto`, then after getting those nodes, then just use `foreach`:

```
$xml_string = '<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="propiedades.xsd" generated="2015-04-28T15:16:46">
<propiedades>
<Descripcion>Excelente casa de dos pisos en condominio en la urbanización Santa Maria De Villa Club, en Carabayllo, con un AT:92m2 y un AC:113m2, cuenta con 3 iluminadas habitaciones, 3 baños, cochera, de estreno, con áreas verdes, piscina, cancha de fútbol, salones para actividades. ¡Para más información contactarse con nuestros agente!ID:   35751</Descripcion>
<Foto1>http://www.alfredograf.com/fotoprop/mini-35751%20-%201.jpg</Foto1>
<Foto2>http://www.alfredograf.com/fotoprop/mini-35751%20-%202.jpg</Foto2>
<Foto3>http://www.alfredograf.com/fotoprop/mini-35751%20-%203.jpg</Foto3>
<Foto4>http://www.alfredograf.com/fotoprop/mini-35751%20-%204.jpg</Foto4>
<Foto5>http://www.alfredograf.com/fotoprop/mini-35751%20-%205.jpg</Foto5>
<Foto6>http://www.alfredograf.com/fotoprop/mini-35751%20-%206.jpg</Foto6>
<Foto7>http://www.alfredograf.com/fotoprop/mini-35751%20-%207.jpg</Foto7>
<Foto8>http://www.alfredograf.com/fotoprop/mini-35751%20-%208.jpg</Foto8>
</propiedades>
</dataroot>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
$fotos = $xml->xpath('//*[substring(name(), 1, 4) = "Foto"]');
foreach($fotos as $foto) {
    echo $foto, '<br/>';
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/OHptT2)

If you don't want to use the xpath route, just use `->getName` to check the node name and use normal PHP string functions to check it:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
foreach($xml->propiedades->children() as $element) {
    if(substr($element->getName(), 0, 4) === 'Foto') {
        echo $element, '<br/>';
    }
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/UnwaoN)

Answer (score 2):

You can access children by using `children()`

Try below code:

```
<?php
$s =<<<EOS
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="propiedades.xsd" generated="2015-04-28T15:16:46">
<propiedades>
<Descripcion>Excelente casa de dos pisos en condominio en la urbanización Santa Maria De Villa Club, en Carabayllo, con un AT:92m2 y un AC:113m2, cuenta con 3 iluminadas habitaciones, 3 baños, cochera, de estreno, con áreas verdes, piscina, cancha de fútbol, salones para actividades. ¡Para más información contactarse con nuestros agente!ID:   35751</Descripcion>
<Foto1>http://www.alfredograf.com/fotoprop/mini-35751%20-%201.jpg</Foto1>
<Foto2>http://www.alfredograf.com/fotoprop/mini-35751%20-%202.jpg</Foto2>
<Foto3>http://www.alfredograf.com/fotoprop/mini-35751%20-%203.jpg</Foto3>
<Foto4>http://www.alfredograf.com/fotoprop/mini-35751%20-%204.jpg</Foto4>
<Foto5>http://www.alfredograf.com/fotoprop/mini-35751%20-%205.jpg</Foto5>
<Foto6>http://www.alfredograf.com/fotoprop/mini-35751%20-%206.jpg</Foto6>
<Foto7>http://www.alfredograf.com/fotoprop/mini-35751%20-%207.jpg</Foto7>
<Foto8>http://www.alfredograf.com/fotoprop/mini-35751%20-%208.jpg</Foto8>
</propiedades>
</dataroot>
EOS;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($s);

foreach ($xml->propiedades as $element) {
    foreach($element->children() as $key => $val) {
        echo "{$key}: {$val}";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that,

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
```

put your whole xml content in  string,

and use reference from here
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_simplexml_load_string.asp