# how to obtain values from an XML doc

Tags: php, xml, api

I have php code connecting to an API:

```
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/MadMimi.class.php');
$mailer = new MadMimi('XXX.org', '000');
$lists = $mailer->Lists();
var_dump($lists);
foreach ($lists as $list) {
echo $list['name']; }
```

**`var_dump`** shows a XML doc in the form:

```
`string '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lists>
  <list id="8" name="#1" subscriber_count="210" display_name="Display name"/>
  <list id="9" name="#2" subscriber_count="2242" display_name="Display name"/>`
```

...(length=2726)

but it only shows the first few lines. How do I make it show all the values?

Also I'm trying to print specific values using the foreach loop but it isn't working and I'm getting the error: `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

If foreach doesn't work how else can I obtain values from the XML doc?

If I do

```
$xml=simplexml_load_string($lists) or die("Error: Cannot create object"); 
print_r($xml);
```

I get:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [list] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => 8 [name] => #1 [subscriber_count] => 210 [display_name] => Display name ) ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => 9 [name] => #2 [subscriber_count] => 2242 [display_name] => Display name ) )
```

how do I write a foreach loop for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29934562/parsing-a-xml-in-php

see this link it may be helpful to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will help you.

```
$lists = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lists>
  <list id="8" name="#1" subscriber_count="210" display_name="Display name"/>
  <list id="9" name="#2" subscriber_count="2242" display_name="Display name"/>
</lists>';


$xml = simplexml_load_string($lists) or die("Error: Cannot create object");

foreach ($xml->children() as $child) {
     // List all the tags
    echo '<pre>';print_r($child);echo '</pre>';

    foreach($child->attributes() as $a => $b) {
    // list all the attributes
        echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I pasted your code from try { $listing... but I got an error: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'catch' (T_CATCH)

Comment: I have tested, and it working fine for me. make sure you have copy correctly.

Comment: I don't have a file source = test.xml, it is on the Madmimi Api. Is this why it isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how your XML looks like but you can read XML in php:

```
$file = "path to XML";

$xml=simplexml_load_file($file) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
print_r($xml);
```

This will return a simple XML object.

If your XML contains sub-children then you can use a `foreach` loop to traverse it.

Comment: I've added my print_r($xml) to the original question. I can't figure out the foreach loop. If you could help me that would be appreciated.

Comment: your get an array object try to beautify your array and you will get your array like this SimpleXMLElement Object (
[list] => Array (
[0] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
[@attributes] => Array (
[id] => 8
[name] => #1
[subscriber_count] => 210
[display_name] => Display name
)
)
[1] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
[@attributes] => Array (
[id] => 9
[name] => #2
[subscriber_count] => 2242
[display_name] => Display name
)
)

Now go through children and traverse it. If you are not sure with traversing then I recommend to read about array traversing

Comment: you can try echo '<pre>'; print_r($xml); echo '</pre>'; so that it would be much readable for you and would be easy to understand and traverse